# Convergence warning when using mixed effect model

Tags: r, regression, glm, mixed-models

I carried out field observations where I counted the number of birds in a plot, I repeated the observation 4 times for different months. The objective of this is to see if land-use influences the number of birds observed.

My formula is bird.count ~ lu + (1|plot)

bird.count a count data with a lot of Zero observations and mean of count = 2 with variance = 5.9, lu is a factor with six levels and plot is a factor with 36 levels the where I carried out the repeated observations. In total I've got 144 observations.

Based on all of this I carried out a negative binomial mixed-effect regression, but got warnings regarding failure to converge and the Std.Error of the coefficients are very high and all the same.

I then tried averaging the bird.count of each plot and then had a total of 36 observations. I did this so I wouldn't have to use a mixed effect model. I ran a glm assuming a Gaussian distribution but the Std.Error of the coefficients are very high and all the same.

The things Ive tried,

```
fit.x10 <- glmer.nb (bird.count ~ 1 + (1|plot) , data= birds.data)  
There were 13 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

fit.x11 <- glmer.nb (bird.count ~ lu + (1|plot), data= birds.data)  
There were 32 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

This gave no warnings

```
fit.y10 <- glmmTMB(
  bird.count ~ (1|plot), data= birds.data, 
  family = nbinom2, ziformula = ~0, se = TRUE, 
  verbose = FALSE, doFit = TRUE
)
```

This gave no warning but the Std.Error of the intercept and coefficients are high and of the same values. For the random effect plot, var= 0.1946 and std= 0.4412

```
fit.y11 <- glmmTMB(
  bird.count ~ lu+  (1|plot), data= birds.data, 
  family = nbinom2, ziformula = ~0, se = TRUE, 
  verbose = FALSE, doFit = TRUE
)
```

This gave no warning but the Std.Error of the intercept and coefficients are high and of the same values

```
fit.z11 <- glm (bird.count ~ lu , data= birds.data.avg, family = gaussian)
```

Any advice on how to diagnose the problem or am I doing something wrong?